# django Count show different value after search

Tags: python, django

I simulate Instagram app.

I have Followers, Actions models.

Each action is done on a "follower".

Many actions can point to one follower.

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    identifier = models.BigIntegerField(
        _("identifier"), unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

class ActionModel(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Follower, verbose_name=_("Target"), 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # username of the done-on action
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )  # django user that performed the action
    is_followed_back = models.BooleanField(_("Followed Back"), null=True, 
        blank=True) # is target followed back
```

Admin panel:

```
# Custom Admin for Follower model
class FollowerAdmin(AdminAdvancedFiltersMixin, NumericFilterModelAdmin, SpecialActions):
...
    # Private method to count been_followed_counter
    def _get_been_followed_count(self, obj):
        return obj.been_followed_count
    _get_been_followed_count.short_description = 'Been Followed Count'
    _get_been_followed_count.admin_order_field = 'been_followed_count'

    # Private method to count follow_back_count
    def _get_follow_back_count(self, obj):
        return obj.follow_back_count
    _get_follow_back_count.short_description = 'Follow Back Count'
    _get_follow_back_count.admin_order_field = 'follow_back_count'
```

I then override the get_queryset for followers:

```
    # Override queryset method to add count's
    def get_queryset(self, request):

        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        qs = qs.annotate(
            been_followed_count=Count('actionmodel', filter=Q(actionmodel__user=request.user))
        ).annotate(
            follow_back_count=Count(
                'actionmodel',
                filter=Q(actionmodel__user=request.user) & Q(actionmodel__is_followed_back=True)
            )
        )
```

I get really strange results in the admin panel:
[no search in panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZDuf.png)

USERNAME : lior___shahar

BEEN FOLLOWED COUNT:5

FOLLOW BACK COUNT:5

This is the True VALUE in actions:
[Value in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSl2M.png)

But once I do SEARCH in FOLLOWERS for the username:
[After Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqaAR.png)

USERNAME : lior___shahar

BEEN FOLLOWED COUNT:320

FOLLOW BACK COUNT:320

...

I don't get what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `distinct=True` to the count annotation.

```
been_followed_count=Count('actionmodel', filter=Q(actionmodel__user=request.user), distinct=True)
```